# Laravel 8: Attempt to read property "id" on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am facing this error 'Attempt to read property "id" on null' in Laravel 8. It was working fine before but in my view I changed $user->id to $user->profile->id and now this is happening. I am logged in the app and I have changed my route accordingly to match profile id, I have also tried clearing cache etc.

Here is my Code:

User Model:

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
//    protected $fillable = [
//        'name',
//        'email',
//        'password',
//    ];

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }

    public function posts ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}
```

Profile Model:

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'profiles';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

ProfilesController:

```
class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        return view ('profiles.index', compact('user'));
    }
    
    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        return view ('profiles.index', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

Route:

```
    Route::get('profile/{profile}', [ProfilesController::class, 'show'])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('profile/{profile}/edit', [ProfilesController::class, 'edit'])->middleware('auth');
```

View:

```
<x-layout>
<section class="py-8 max-w-4xl mx-auto">
    <h1 class="text-lg font-bold mb-8 pb-2 border-b">
        @if ($user->id == auth()->user()->id)
        Hello {{ $user->name }}, welcome to your profile.
        @else
        {{ $user->name }}'s Profile.
        @endif
    </h1>
    <div class="flex">
        <aside class="w-48 flex-shrink-0">
            <h4 class="font-semibold mb-4">
                Navigation
            </h4>
            <ul style="max-width: 75%">
                <li>
                    <a href="/profile/{{ $user->profile->id }}" class="{{ request()->is('profile/'.$user->profile->id) ? 'text-blue-500' : '' }}">View Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                        @if ($user->id == auth()->user()->id)
                            <a href="/profile/{{ $user->profile->id }}/edit" class="{{ request()->is('profile/'.$user->profile->id.'/edit') ? 'text-blue-500' : '' }}">Edit Profile</a>
                        @endif
                </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <main class="flex-1">
            <x-panel>
                <div class="flex flex-col">
                    <div class="-my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
                        <div class="py-2 align-middle inline-block min-w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                            <div class="shadow overflow-hidden border-b border-gray-200 sm:rounded-lg">
                                <div class="flex flex-row grid-cols-12">
                                    <div class="flex flex-col col-span-4 row-span-full justify-items-start flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 grid-cols-4">
                                        <div class="flex flex-row">
                                            <img src="http://i.pravatar.cc/60?u={{ $user->profile->id }}" alt="" width="" height="" class="rounded-full h-24 w-24 flex m-2">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex flex-col col-span-8 justify-right grid-cols-8 text-sm">
                                        <div class="flex flex-row">
                                            <div class="flex flex-col col-span-2 font-semibold">
                                                <div class="pt-3">Name:</div>
                                                <div class="pt-3">Email:</div>
                                                <div class="pt-3">About:</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="flex flex-col col-span-10">
                                                <div class="pt-3 pl-4 text-justify">{{ $user->profile->name }}</div>
                                                <div class="pt-3 pl-4 text-justify">{{ $user->profile->email }}</div>
                                                <div class="pt-3 pl-4 text-justify"><p>{{ $user->profile->description }}</p></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </x-panel>
        </main>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It says "attempting to read property `id` on `null" since it was not happening with `$user->id` but is happening with `$user->profile->id` the logical conclusion is that `$user->profile` is null i.e. the user has no associated profile or the relationship is not set up correctly. Can you share the database structure for the user and profile tables? Also if your profile route takes a user id I suggest naming the route parameter `Route::get('/profile/{user}',...)` so it's clear what the route parameter is.

Comment: Here is the db structure:
`Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });`
I was using user id in route before and the relationship was working fine. I changed the page route to be load by profile id and this happened.

Comment: better to dd($user) in your controller. I think route model binding is not correct ``Route::get('profile/{profile}'`` and you must use the same variable in Controller ``public function show(User $profile)``

Comment: Guys it is resolved, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are passing a `Profile` model as indicated by your routes, but the method is looking for a `User` model.

Show and Edit have a `User` Model as a parameter. If you pass the `Profile` `id`, the method is gonna find the `User` model by `id` but with the `id` of the `Profile` model and not the `user_id` of the `Profile` model.

You will need to change the methods to:

```php
public function show(Profile $profile)
{
    $user = $profile->user;
    return view ('profiles.index', compact('user'));
}

public function edit(Profile $profile)
{
    $user = $profile->user;
    return view ('profiles.index', compact('user'));
}
```

With this code the `Profile` model is found and via the relationship the `User` is obtained and passed to the view.

Comment: Thank you, this was the obvious solution which I weren't thinking off, it is working now.

Comment: @BilalYousaf That is good to hear, would you mind accepting my answer then? :)

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function edit($id)
    {
        $table = Table::find($id);
        return view('tables.edit', compact('table'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $table = Table::find($id);
        $table->update($request->all());
        return redirect('/tables');
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).